# Android app path on emulator

Tags: android, html

Hi i have to do connectivity between browser and android app. I referred the link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser.][1]
They have suggested to use special scheme.

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="my.special.scheme" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

and path would be like `<a href="my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here">`
in your web app.

I am running it on emulator. through localhost address. What will be the exact path 
for special scheme

i have given

```
<intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and in web app on button action

```
   <FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="Integration://hello">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Clickable Button">
</FORM>
```

can u tell me where i am doing mistake. or what would be the correct path then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `"http://Integration"`, "http" is the scheme. Replace it with your scheme. 
`action=Integration://whatever`

Comment: ok. Do i have to pass any parameters where u have written whatever?

Comment: Giving an error. the webpage at http://Integration/? might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Comment: Please refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2958870/1321873 which correctly explains the usage. Can you please post the code that you have used?

Comment: Can you please check if the scheme is working in a link (an anchor tag) first?

Comment: http://Integration on button click is not working.. Can u tell me if i am passing a path on button click. How the browser will identify it is android app path?? i think it is checking a web address.When i am replacing http://Integration with other google.com and other site address then it is working.otherwise not

Comment: ok finally it is giving index out of bound exception error while opening an app. the code in activity i have written  Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        String scheme = data.getScheme(); // "http"
        String host = data.getHost(); // "twitter.com"
        List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
       // String first = params.get(0); // "hello"
        
        System.out.println(scheme);
        //System.out.println(first); and onAction ACTION="Integration://hello". please tell me what is the mistake

Comment: When you specify `Integration://hello", you have only host part, and no path and hence the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. If you specify `Integration://hello/path/`, you will receive "path" in `first`.

Comment: yeah finally my code works here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615319/taking-uri-data-through-intent-in-android/10615397#10615397