# Taking uri data through intent in android

Tags: android, html

Hi i have to do connectivity between android app and browser. So while clicking a button on browser it should redirect to android app. in android activity i have written

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData(); 
        if (data.equals(null)) { 
            System.out.println("Data is null");
        } else { 
            String scheme = data.getScheme();
            System.out.println(scheme);
            String host = data.getHost(); 
            int port = data.getPort(); 
            List<String> params = data.getPathSegments();
            String first = params.get(0); // "hello"
            System.out.println(first);
```

and in manifest i have already given

```
<intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="Integration" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

in html on button click i have given `<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="Integration://1">`

it is throwing a indexoutofboundexception.
Please tell me where is the mistake

**Updated**
**I was unnecessarily using intent in an activity. By removing that n parameter in html5 my app is running successfully now.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting answer from: [How to listen for a custom URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471503/how-to-listen-for-a-custom-uri)

> To register a protocol in your android app, add an extra block to the AndroidManifest.xml

I modified the code a little, but thought I'd quote the source too

```
<manifest>
 <application>
   <activity android:name=".activityToCall">
           <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="scheme" android:host="path"/>
            </intent-filter>
   </activity>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

Then when a url matching your schema is opened your app will be called to handle it I assume.
Taking into consideration that `scheme` and `path`correspond to this:

```
scheme://host/path
```

After that, in the activity you've set in the manifest to handle this stuff:

```
Uri data = getIntent().getData(); 
if (!data.equals(null)){ 
    String scheme = data.getScheme(); 
    //Or whatever you needed
}
```

Comment: i updated the code. It is giving index out of bound exception. I dont no y

Comment: `params.get(0)` no parameters means you can't get the first parameter, and therefor `inderOutOfBounds`

Comment: ok. but in html ACTION="Integration://h "> i am passing parameter "h" and in activity code i am taking String first = params.get(0);. If it don't work so in action can i write alone ACTION="Integration://">

Comment: It is running finally. Thanx a ton. I was doing a silly mistake :)

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it was useful, I'm glad I was able to help a little.